# .Net AS400 terminal emulator recommendations?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ibm-midrange, terminal-emulator

We may be switching our terminal emulation software soon... I'd like to see if there are any recommendations out there for AS400 terminal emulation software that includes a good .net api.

Just to head this one off at the pass... Yes, I'd love to get the iSeries developer tools and interact directly with the server, but we are limited to interacting with it through our in house application, so I'm stuck with automating that.

I also wasn't sure where else to ask this question, so if it is not quite appropriate for this forum, please accept my appologies, but I'm also pretty sure this would be a great place to get a recommendation or two.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Not this site, but try [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for?  Are you looking for a .NET data provider or for a terminal emulator that includes access to the emulator itself via APIs?

Comment: @Charles You got it.  However, it looks like we had an application with a .net api under our noses the whole time.  If anyone has a Pro/Con on Reflection 2011 from Attachmate, I'm all ears.  We have been using an older version, but apparently purchased the newer and never updated.

Comment: I'm a build engineer on the Reflection 2011 team, so I am a bit biased.  But I don't think anyone would begrudge me saying that should check out the product documentation and API examples to see if they will fit your needs.  And since you are a customer, feel free to contact our support if you feel that the product is lacking.

Comment: @JasonMArcher I was just looking at the documentation earlier and it appears to have exactly what I was looking for - no com objects, so I'm pretty confident we'll be using it.  As I said, we apparently already purchased it as well, so I'm thinking it's pretty likely we'll be rolling it out soon.  We have a testing terminal that I'm in the process of having moved over to my desk as we speak.

Answer (score 2):

The standard IBM i Access includes a .NET provider for data access.

See [IBM i Access for Windows : Programming](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaik/rzaikoverview.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The standard IBM i Access for Windows includes a subset of the full Personal Communications product.  The subset does include

```
Host Access Class Library (HACL) for ActiveX and C++ 
Emulator High Level Language API (EHLLAPI) for C/C++
```

In addition, the PC5250 software can function as a DDE server.

That being said, I did notice that the stand-alone Personal Communications product includes:

```
Primary Interop Assemblies for Microsoft .NET
```

from here: 
ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/network/pcomm/publications/pcomm_59/HACP_V6_G325-2065-03_0804b.pdf

Comment: I think I should have been more specific... Yes, this can be used in .net, but specifically I'm looking for something that does not use COM, I'm looking for a .net api, not a com api that can be used in .net, but you certainly could use this in .net.